# Does WCF message security actually encrypt message contents?

Tags: c#, wcf, security, certificate, nettcpbinding

I have read the documentation provided at MSDN, and some other posts on this site. However, its still a bit unclear whether WCF (specifically, NetTcpBinding) will actually encrypt message **contents** when using message security w/ certificates. Does anyone know for sure?

For instance you can specify both transport and message credentials in your config:

```
       <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"
                   negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
       </security>
```

As far as I can tell the MSDN documentation implies that message security simply relies on either username/password or certificate-based authentication (negotiation), but doesn't specifically state that the message themselves are actually encrypted at the message level.

For instance if I use ONLY message security, with certificate-based negotiation, I don't think message contents are actually encrypted (ie. a packet sniffer could intercept the raw message contents -- even if the service enforces authentication)?

If true message-level encryption is possible (using NetTcpBinding) how is it done in code? I believe this is related to the AlgorithmSuite, though I'm not sure,

```
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = new System.ServiceModel.Security.TripleDesSecurityAlgorithmSuite();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this fully answers your question, but according to [this article](http://www.codemag.com/article/0611051) TCP encrypts by default.

> NetTcpBinding is secure by default. Specifically, callers must provide
>   Windows credentials for authentication and all message packets are
>   signed and encrypted over TCP protocol.

In other words, if you customise the configuration but use a security mode other than 'None',

> By default, all secure WCF bindings will encrypt and sign messages.
>   You cannot disable this for transport security, however, for message
>   security you may wish to disable this for debugging purposes, or when
>   an alternate method of protection is used such as IPSec.

Comment: I decided to just sniff the packets myself using Wireshark, and I can confirm that this is true. Apparently windows takes care of the encryption itself for domain / trusted domain communication. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

WCF can encrypt message contents with a netTcpBinding. The easiest way to see this is to add [diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) to your .config file and output an svclog file. You can actually see the encrypted message with the svctraceviewer.exe tool

Here's some more info (which you may have already read) [WCF NetTcpBinding Security - how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536522/wcf-nettcpbinding-security-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a late answer. But here is something i stumbled upon on MSDN.

> Message security makes the message secure regardless of what transport you use to transmit the message, and the security context is directly embedded inside the message.

[MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137(v=vs.110).aspx)